# answer.php not working correctly

Tags: php, html, logging, record

Here is my code.

```
<?php
header ('Location: example.com');
$handle = fopen("entry.txt", "a");
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
    fwrite($handle, $variable);
    fwrite($handle, "=");
    fwrite($handle, $value);
    fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>
```

I want it to record an entered answer in a separate .txt file, however it is not doing this. Instead it is opening the "entry.txt" and leaving blank spaces inside.

Any clues as to what the issue could be? I have been attempting to solve this for nearly an hour now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works properly. You probably need to chmod your file to have write access, as it's probably set to 666 or such.

Also, when you try to redirect to different domains, you must add the protocol; otherwise, the header() will send you to http://yourdomain.com/example.com

```
// WRONG
header ('Location: example.com');

// RIGHT
header ('Location: http://example.com/'); // Trailing slashes are a good habit
```

Answer (score 0):

use is_writable($filename) to first check if file is writable.